# "Ich rühme mich damit,...."

Tags: grammatical-case

> Er kann sich rühmen, als erster Mensch den Mond betreten zu haben
>   Aus dem Duden

In der Regel benutzt man das Verb "rühmen" in der reflexiven Form mit dem Genitiv. Sollte der Genitiv aber erhalten bleiben, wenn ich einen Substantiv benutzen will? Z. B.

> Er kann sich **mit der Tatsache/damit** rühmen, als erster Mensch den Mond betreten zu haben.

Ist dieser Satz möglich?

Comment: Das Verb regiert nur so lange den Kasus, bis eine Präposition auftaucht. Dann zieht es den Schwanz ein und überlässt der Präposition das Feld.

Comment: Ja, dieser Satz ist möglich.

Comment: In "Mit der Tatsache" ist "Tatsache" ein Wort im Dativ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Für mich ist

> *Er kann sich **mit** der Tatsache rühmen, als erster Mensch den Mond betreten zu haben

fehlerhaftes Deutsch, oder wenn nicht fehlerhaft, dann doch ein Balanceakt auf der schmalen Grenze zwischen echtem Fehler und ungelenkem Stil; ergo: Ein ordentlich arbeitender Redakteur wird diesen Satz unweigerlich verbessern.

Gute Sätze sind:

> Er kann sich der Tatsache rühmen, als erster Mensch den Mond betreten zu haben.
>
> Er kann sich rühmen, als erster Mensch den Mond betreten zu haben.

Fazit: "sich rühmen" will immer einen Genitiv (*wessen?*); "sich rühmen **mit**" sollte man vermeiden, auch wenn man es gelegentlich aus nachlässigem Munde hören mag. Wer so spricht, wird sich jedoch nicht

> mit Ruhm bekleckern.

Hingegen kann man sich gut und gerne **mit** etwas **brüsten**:

> Er brüstet sich damit, als erster Mensch den Mond betreten zu haben.